# CMake not finding Qt5 when trying to create Qt5 Project in CLion on Linux

Tags: linux, cmake, qt5, clion

I am getting the following CMake error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

In my CMakeLists.txt, there is this line:

```
if (NOT CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    message(WARNING "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is not defined, you may need to set it "
            "(-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=\"path/to/Qt/lib/cmake\" or -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/include/{host}/qt{version}/ on Ubuntu)")
endif ()
```

So I did what it says and set my PREFIX_PATH to "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/".
However, the error I get says that CMake cannot find "qt5-config.cmake", which is located at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5" and not "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/", so I tried setting the "Qt5_DIR" to that directory (since it says in the error to set it to a dir that contains the above files) but still without success. Any ideas why it cant find the files it needs?

edit:

my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/")
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(QT_VERSION 5)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS Core Gui Widgets)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)


if (NOT CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    message(WARNING "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is not defined, you may need to set it "
            "(-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=\"path/to/Qt/lib/cmake\" or -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/include/{host}/qt{version}/ on Ubuntu)")
endif ()

find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION} COMPONENTS ${REQUIRED_LIBS} REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED})
```

note that the file has been auto-generated by CLion, all I did was change the path according to what is specified in the if-Block

Comment: That prefix path is invalid. The _check_ that emits a warning if the prefix path is empty is invalid. You need to show your full CMakeLists.txt, the command you used to run it, and the output of that command.

Comment: @AlexReinking added the CMakeLists.txt.
what is invalid about that path? And what is invalid about that check, it was autogenerated by Clion.